# extrapolate data within the foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, subset

Take the following example, I create a data.frame `df1`.
For each iteration, we mix up the order of `df1` and rename it `df2`
We then apply conditions to df2, that are:

- when `df2[1,1] == 1`, then we want to subset `df2` so that we remove the case of `df2$B==125`, and if `df2[1,1] != 1`, then make no action
- as a second step when `df2[1,1] == 3`, then we want to subset `df2` so that we remove the case of `df2$B==108`, and if `df2[1,1] != 1`, then make no action

But I dont know how to code this step. Can someone fill in the gaps below.
When we run the code, the output should sucessfully return values between 9 and 10.

```
require(doParallel)
set.seed(123)
A <- 1:10
B <- c(106,144,131,107,125,108,105,119,112,127)
df1 <- data.frame(A,B)

m <- 100

Sample = foreach(i=c(1:m)) %do%{

  #shuffle order of data
  df2 <- df1[sample(1:nrow(df1)), ]
  df2
  # when df2[1,1] == 1 then remove df2$B==125, otherwise leave df2 as is

  # or
  # when df2[1,1] == 3 then remove df2$B==108, otherwise leave df2 as is

  length(df2$A)
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result of the action 'remove df2$B==125'? Do you want to substitute it by some other value, e..g 0 or NA?

Comment: No, i just wish to remove it from the dataset, so that df2 would become a length of 9

Comment: You'd like to delete the entire row then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
require(doParallel)
set.seed(123)
A <- 1:10
B <- c(106,144,131,107,125,108,105,119,112,127)
df1 <- data.frame(A,B)

m <- 100

Sample = foreach(i=c(1:m)) %do%{

    #shuffle order of data
    df2 <- df1[sample(1:nrow(df1)), ]
    df2
    if (df2[1,1]==1) df2 <- df2[-which(df2$B==125),]
    if (df2[1,1]==3) df2 <- df2[-which(df2$B==108),]

    print(nrow(df2))
}
```